# Converting a file URL to its Physical address

Tags: url

Some of the websites are blocked on my network.In order to access the contents of a site can I convert a URL into physical address of a file ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  When you're visiting a website, a file's URL *is* its address.

Comment: @David                                                                                  Suppose there is a video l want to download. If the site is not blocked then if I click on URL then it automatically redirects to its physical address and downloads it but not if it is blocked. So is there any way I can get its physical address directly ?

Comment: What you're describing makes no sense.  A URL *is* an address.  If you're blocked from visiting a URL, then you can't visit that URL.  Either you're not describing the problem effectively or you have some fundamental misunderstandings of what URLs and web requests are.